# repeat events on certain dates node.js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I have a function in which stores the current date, and time (`timestamp`) in mysql db.

formatted like so:

```
'2022-01-28 13:00:00.000000'
```

The way this gets inserted into my table is like so:

```
    var insertNewEvent = "INSERT INTO SCHEDULE (DATE,LOCATION,ASSIGNED_TRAINER,CLIENT_USERNAME,ENDDATE, ID, EVENT_NAME, SESSION_STATUS) VALUES('" + eventDetails.eventDate + " " + eventDetails.eventStartTime + "', '" + eventDetails.eventLocation + "', '" + eventDetails.trainerUserName + "', '" + eventDetails.selectedClient + "', '" + eventDetails.eventDate + " " + eventDetails.eventEndTime + "', '" + uniqueID + "', '" + eventDetails.nameOfEvent + "', '" + session_status + "')"
```

and yes, I am changing this query as I know it is unsafe and not right.

but now what I want is for example, I want to say insert the same event (all same event details), but have it repeat on the day i inserted it for, and then every let's say `monday`, `wednesday`, `friday` after that. I am a little but stumped on how to go about this, I was hoping someone could guide me. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try creating a middleware to handle it, for example:

```
var checkDate= Date.UTC(new Date().getFullYear(), new Date().getMonth(),
              (new Date().getDate() + 1));
const myMiddleware= async(req, res, next) =>{
    if(Date.now()>= checkDate){
        checkDate= Date.UTC(new Date().getFullYear(), new Date().getMonth(),
                   (new Date().getDate() + 1));
        // your code here
        
    }
    next();
}
```

then use it

```
app.use(myMiddleware);
```